# Trying to get spaces between codons and stop the generation when reaching a certain codon for RNA to protein simulation

Tags: python, function, range, character, spaces

Here's some things I need help with.
But first of all, please let me pull up the code first.

```
from base_printer import *

def dna_complement(dna):
  coup = ""
  for letter in dna:
    if letter == "C":
      coup += "G"
    if letter == "G":
      coup += "C"
    if letter == "A":
      coup += "T"
    if letter == "T":
      coup += "A"
  return coup
  

def convert_to_rna(dna):
  coup2 = ""
  for letter in dna:
    if letter == "C":
      coup2 += "G"
    if letter == "G":
      coup2 += "C"
    if letter == "A":
      coup2 += "U"
    if letter == "T":
      coup2 += "A"
  return coup2

def translate(rna):
  amino_acid = ""
  for i in range(len(rna)-2):
    three_letter = rna[i:i+3]
    if three_letter in CODON_TABLE:
      amino_acid += CODON_TABLE[three_letter]
      i += 2 
  return amino_acid

CODON_TABLE = {'UUU':'Phe','UUC':'Phe','UUA':'Leu','UUG':'Leu','CUU':'Leu','CUC':'Leu','CUA':'Leu','CUG':'Leu','AUU':'Ile','AUC':'Ile','AUA':'Ile','AUG':'Met','GUU':'Val','GUC':'Val','GUA':'Val','GUG':'Val','UCU':'Ser','UCC':'Ser','UCA':'Ser','UCG':'Ser','CCU':'Pro','CCC':'Pro','CCA':'Pro','CCG':'Pro','ACU':'Thr','ACC':'Thr','ACA':'Thr','ACG':'Thr','GCU':'Ala','GCC':'Ala','GCA':'Ala','GCG':'Ala','UAU':'Tyr','UAC':'Tyr','UAA':'STOP','UAG':'STOP','CAU':'His','CAC':'His','CAA':'Gln','CAG':'Gln','AAU':'Asn','AAC':'Asn','AAA':'Lys','AAG':'Lys','GAU':'Asp','GAC':'Asp','GAA':'Glu','GAG':'Glu','UGU':'Cys','UGC':'Cys','UGA':'STOP','UGG':'Trp','CGU':'Arg','CGC':'Arg','CGA':'Arg','CGG':'Arg','AGU':'Ser','AGC':'Ser','AGA':'Arg','AGG':'Arg','GGU':'Gly','GGC':'Gly','GGA':'Gly','GGG':'Gly'}

dna="AAGAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTCTTAGCGGGGCCACATCGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGTTACAGCGAGCATAC" 


def main():
  print("\nWelcome to the DNA program: The Code of Life.")
  print("\nSample DNA strand:\n")
  print("Regular DNA:")
  print_bases(dna)
  print("DNA after complement: ")
  dna2 = dna_complement(dna)
  print_bases(dna2)
  print("DNA after RNA convertion: ")
  rna = convert_to_rna(dna)
  print_bases(rna)
  print("The result of translation: ")
  amino_acid = translate(rna)
  print_bases(amino_acid)


main()
```

I was trying to get the Codon printing out as everyone can see, the output of translation have been successfully printed out as

```
PHESERLEUSERLEUTYRTHRARGGLYVALSTOPASNTHRGLNARGGLYGLYGLYGLYALAPROARGGLYGLUARGGLYASPTHRARGASPTHRARGASPTHRARGGLUARGGLUASNILESERARGALAPROPROPROARGGLYVALCYSVALSTOPSERALAPROARGGLYVALTRPGLYALAARGASPTHRARGGLYGLYASPTHRARGGLYGLYGLYASPTHRPROLEUSERPROPROHISTHRPROARGGLYGLYGLYVALTRPGLYALAPROARGGLYALAGLNASNMETCYSVALSERARGALALEUSERARGVALTYRMET
```

Now what I want to do is to have spaces separating each of the Codons listed in the program outputs and stop the generation once it reached UAA/UGA/UAG which is what I'm trying to figure out. But now the problem is I don't know where I should even start with which is embarrassing.

An example of output I want: Phe Ser Leu Ser Leu Tyr (Stops once reaching the UAA/UGA/UAG)

Would someone be willing to offer some tips?

Edit: Here's the information of base_print , it basically prints the output out in different colors

```
import colorama as cr
cr.init(autoreset=True)

def print_bases(string):
    """prints dna/rna bases with color coding for each base"""
    for char in string.upper():
        if char == "A":
            print(cr.Back.BLACK + cr.Fore.GREEN + cr.Style.BRIGHT + char, end="")
        elif char == "C":
            print(cr.Back.BLACK + cr.Fore.YELLOW + cr.Style.BRIGHT + char, end="")
        elif char == "T":
            print(cr.Back.BLACK + cr.Fore.BLUE + cr.Style.BRIGHT + char, end="")
        elif char == "G":
            print(cr.Back.BLACK + cr.Fore.MAGENTA + cr.Style.BRIGHT + char, end="")
        elif char == "U":
            print(cr.Back.BLACK + cr.Fore.WHITE + char, end="")
        else:
            print(char, end="") 
    print()
```

Comment: Oh yeah also big credit for a user called Jack Deeth, he's the one that helped me to rebuild the whole function to make it actually available for work.

Comment: It's unclear where these Codons that you want to change the printing of are being printed — if it's from the `print_bases()` function, then we're probably going to need to see the code for it which currently isn't included in your question.

Comment: @martineau Be right back, I'll check this up real quick

Comment: @martineau Sorry I missed it, I'll pull them up really quick

Comment: OK, you can do something like what's in @Tobi208's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71073823/355230) in at the beginning of `print_bases()` and apply it to the `string` argument — it'll add the spaces.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the help, will keep in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it

```py
def translate(rna):
    amino_acid = []
    for i in range(len(rna) - 2):
        three_letter = rna[i:i + 3]
        if three_letter in ['UAA', 'UGA', 'UAG']:
            break
        if three_letter in CODON_TABLE:
            amino_acid.append(CODON_TABLE[three_letter])
            i += 2
    return ' '.join(amino_acid)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'll check this up right now!

Comment: Result gotten, seems like it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to print everything prior to `'STOP'` sliced into 3 characters each, here's an extension of your `main` function:

```py
    res = amino_acid[:amino_acid.index('STOP')]  if 'STOP' in amino_acid else amino_acid
    res = ' '.join(res[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(res), 3))
    print(res)
```

Alternatively, if you only want to translate until you reach a stop codon **and** already have you amino acid with spaces, here's a modification of your `translate` function:

```
def translate(rna):
    amino_acid = ""
    for i in range(len(rna) - 2):
        three_letter = rna[i:i + 3]
        if three_letter in CODON_TABLE:
            next_aa = CODON_TABLE[three_letter]
            if next_aa == 'STOP':
                return amino_acid.strip()
            amino_acid += ' ' + next_aa
            i += 2
    return amino_acid.strip()
```

Output:

```
Phe Ser Leu Ser Leu Tyr Thr Arg Gly Val
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for coming to help, please, let me check it up really quick and I'll give you the response as soon as possible!

Comment: I added an alternative

Comment: Alright, thank you, let me check it again

Comment: Uh, sorry for bothering again but, when I run it the program shows up "substring not found" , is this supposed so happen?

Comment: The solutions are two separate options, don't combine them. But you're right, the first option would fail if 'STOP' wasn't in the string. I fixed it.

Comment: Got it, both works, anyway thank you so much for coming to help! Hope it wasn't unpleasant for you!